# preg_replace regex tags not being replaced

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Hoping you can help. Pretty new to regex and although I have written this regex it doesnt seem to match. I dont recieve an error message so im assuming the syntax is correct but its just not being applied?

I want the regex to replace content like

> ***{foo}bar{/foo}***  with
>   ***bar***

Here is my code:

```
$regex = "#([{].*?[}])(.*?)([{]/.*?[}])#e";
$return = preg_replace($regex,"('$2')",$return);
```

Hope someone can help. Not sure why it doesnt seem to work.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: "does not work" is not really an error message .. did you at least try something like http://www.rexv.org/ to see what exactly you are selecting with that regexp ?

Comment: "Doesn't seem to work" is rather useless - can't you say *how specifically* it doesn't work? One thing I can see right away is that this will match `{foo}bar{/foo}`, but also `{foo}bar{/baz}` - use a backreference to fix.

Comment: If I was getting an error message I would have pasted it in. Since I dont get an error message im assuming its not a syntax problem but rather me writing something wrong so the regex is not triggered. Hence me posting here to see is someone more experienced can see what im typing wrong.

Comment: Thing is, it doesn't have to be an error message. How did you know it was wrong? That's what you should have written. "It only strips one tag but I have 3 in my string" or "if I write `{a}{b}foo{/b}{/a}`, I'm left with `{b}foo{/a}`, and that's not what I wanted" would have been great. If it's simply not matching, "it doesn't match" is better than "it's not working".

Comment: Apologies, I have edited my question. Thank you to everyone for your input and explanations :) Pauls example worked great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex [does work](http://codepad.org/bRjHx0u1), however it isn't smart enough to know that the end tag has to be the same as the start tag. I would use this instead. I've also simplified it a little:

```
$regex = '#{([^}]*)}(.*?)\{/\\1}#';

echo preg_replace('{foo}bar{/foo}', '$2', $str); // outputs "bar"
```

[**Codepad**](http://codepad.org/rpWf0JDy)

Answer (score 2):

Refering to my comment above:

```
#(?:[{](.*?)[}])(.*?)(?:[{]/\1[}])#
```

uses a backreference to keep the tags equal. Also, I used non-capture parentheses to keep the useless groups out: `$1` will be the tag name, and `$2` will be the tag content.

Note that you will have to apply the replacement several times if your tags can nest.